# How to find a Graph Embedding given a metric space?

Tags: graphs, approximation

I am interested to learn more about [topological graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520768/whats-the-relation-between-topology-and-graph-theory) and [Graph Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding).

Assume I have a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), $d \colon M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ and a graph, $G=(V,E)$.

What is a rigorous way to define a valid [embedding](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEmbedding.html) of $G$ given $d$ and how to find such an [embedding](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33043/algorithm-for-embedding-a-graph-with-metric-constraints)?

Edit: I found this [post](https://medium.com/@eliorcohen/node2vec-embeddings-for-graph-data-32a866340fef) about embedding graphs.

Comment: This is explained on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus, but I don't see how this first hit on google wiki page addresses my concerns.  Maybe I don't fully understand it though.

Comment: That looks like a very broad question.   I count at least 3 questions here.  Please ask only  one question per post.  I suggest you edit your post to focus on only the first question.  Then, you'll probably need to tell us more.  What is the context?  What properties do you want the embedding to have?  What resources have you already looked at, and why have you rejected them?  In what way did the definition on the Wikipedia page fall short?  It sounds like you ran across this notion or phrase somewhere; can you tell us about where you ran across it and what the context was?

Comment: You've edited this to reduce it from 3 questions to 2 questions, but it's still 2 separate questions ("how to define" vs "how to find it").  Please ask only one question per post.  And, I don't see that you've addressed the other feedback.  You say the definition on Wikipedia didn't address your concerns, but you haven't explained why, or what your concerns are, specifically.

Comment: Also, as stated, the question seems to be a purely mathematical one, with no computational content. As such, I think it’s much better suited to [math.se] than this site.

Comment: As noted by David Richerby, this is a mathematics question. Please ask it on [mathematics.se]. Moderators cannot migrate questions that are over two months old.